# While rotating img in jquery. my first img is rotation perfectly but the second img is taking the value from previous img and than continue

Tags: jquery, image, rotation

If you drag images from top to bottom block..

and press the rotate button, than image will rotate and try to do it for two three images and than you will see the current image is taking the value from previous image and than continue..

so i want the image to be have separate functionality / not depend on others..

```
var value = 0    
 $(".rotate_img").rotate({    
    bind:    
 {    
click: function(){    
value +=45;    
$(ui.draggable).rotate({ animateTo:value})    
}    
}    
});
```

Here is the link for jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/qzgt4p5h/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to each image a custom attribute to save it's rotation degree `data-rot="0"`, then use this to update the rotation angle as follows :

```
$(".rotate_img").rotate({
              bind:
              {
                click: function(){
                   var value = parseInt($(ui.draggable).attr("data-rot"));
                    //console.log($(ui.draggable).attr("data-rot"));
                  value +=45;
                  $(ui.draggable).rotate({ animateTo:value});
                    $(ui.draggable).attr("data-rot",value);
                }
              }
            });
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzgt4p5h/2/).

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again.. but i am very new in coding. Actually when i am adding this resizable function in my code than drag is not working and the object is behaving very strangely......Can you help me in this matter.. $(ui.draggable).resizable();     http://jsfiddle.net/qzgt4p5h/3/

Comment: sorry i was too busy.. I am not much into resizable.. It's gonna take me some time to try to figure out this which I don't have now.. For the mean time take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c38WX/31/) and see if it helps, and I will get back to you as soon as possible..